# The value for an unchecked checkbox in the Accounts.ui.config form always gets passed to my profile object

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using the [accounts-ui-bootstrap3](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) package. It is based off the regular accounts-ui package

I have a checkbox in the sign up form to check if someone is a teacher. Whenever But even if someone doesn't check the "teacher" checkbox, the "teacher" value is always saved as "true" in the profile object.

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {},   
    extraSignupFields: [{
        fieldName: 'teacher',
        fieldLabel: 'Teacher?',
        inputType: 'checkbox',
        visible: true,
        saveToProfile: true
    }]
});
```

Which gives me this in the HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="login-teacher" name="login-teacher" value="true">
    Teacher</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the *exact* same problem with the same package. After spending a while trying to figure it out by playing around with it, I put it into my app anyway and the problem suddenly disappeared for seemingly no reason - as of this morning, the checkbox returns `false` if not ticked.

But that's of no help to you!

First, here is my replication of the problem on meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/DAQ8wF63F2AQafQjd/Accounts%20ui%20test

It looks like this happens because when the checkbox is created, it has a value of true, so it always returns true. Like I said, my problem magically sorted itself out despite this, but if you are still having problems you can maybe try the following:

- Set `saveToProfile: false`
- Find whether the box is checked using something like `$("#login-teacher").prop("checked")`
- Then either:

  - just add that property to your user's profile with `Users.update()`
  - or use `Accounts.onCreateUser()` from the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)

Otherwise do update this if you have found the answer in the time since you asked the question!